# Execute consequent Switch cases even if it doesn't match powershell?

Tags: powershell

So I have the following switch case and suppose if i give input 3 i should get output

Case 3
Case 4
Case 5
Case 6

and if i give input 5 then O/P : Case 5 Case 6

```
switch(1)
{
case 1 : { write-host "Case 1"}

case 2 : { write-host "Case 2"}

case 3 : { write-host "Case 3"}

case 4 : { write-host "Case 4"}

case 5 : { write-host "Case 5"}

case 6 : { write-host "Case 6"}

}
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Use comparisons in your case statements, specifically `-ge` (greater or equal):

```
$val=3
switch($val)  {
    {(1 -ge $_)} { write-host "Case 1" }
    {(2 -ge $_)} { write-host "Case 2" }
    {(3 -ge $_)} { write-host "Case 3" }
    {(4 -ge $_)} { write-host "Case 4" }

}
```

This works because Powershell continues to evaluate the possible matches even after it matches the first time - to avoid this, you would have to add a `break` into each execute block.

Comment: Think you've got your brackets and parens a little fouled on the conditions. {(...}} closing should be )}?

Comment: Yeah, and the wrong order for the comparison. I need a coffee :)